# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь тире?

Таким образом, достигается меньше утечек, а значит, меньше эксплуатационных расходов.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "таким образом" бывает вводным, а бывает обстоятельством образа действия.

Ваше предложение можно понять двояко.

Если Вы подводите итог, то выражение "таким образом" является вводным словосочетанием, и запятая нужна.

Если же словосочетание "таким образом" равно по значению выражению "таким способом" (достигается (как?) таким образом), то запятая не нужна, это обстоятельство.

Где вы хотели поставить тире? После ЗНАЧИТ? Или перед ним? Перед "а значит" тире не ставится, запятая тут побеждает. А после "значит" возможно на месте отсутствующего глагола "достигается". Тогда и запятая исчезнет.*Таким образом, достигается меньше утечек, а значит - меньше эксплуатационных расходов.*

Comment: Да, Вы правы. В контексте из которого взято предложение, подводится итог, поэтому запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном вами примере, запятая не нужна. Однако при более широком контексте запятая все же может понадобится.

Дополнение.

Случайно нашел ваше предложение в интернете. Указанная запятая поставлена верно!